# Reading coordinates from Matrix file WITHOUT 2D arrays?

Tags: c++, file, matrix, fstream, bioinformatics

I'm currently working on a program (bioinformatics project) that involves reading multiple files, including a matrix, and outputting the results onto another file. What I'm having the most trouble with is how I would go about reading the matrix file like a coordinate system (for lack of a better term)? Is there a simple way to do this without using 2D arrays? For example, if I have the following amino acids in:

fileA: CTTNCLAPLA
fileB: CTTNSITPVA

The program would then read the two files, compare each letter, and refer to the matrix to find the number corresponding to the two letters, which in turn determines the probability of a letter in fileA mutating to a letter in fileB.

Since the first letter in each file is C, the program would read the matrix and output in a separate file:

```
C T T N C L A P L A
| | | | . : : | : |
C T T N S I T P V A
```

The "." means that the number according to the matrix was 0 but not the same letter, "|" means that the letter is the same, and the ":" means that the number was greater than zero but not the same letter.

Here is part of the matrix (the rest wouldn't fit):
NOTE: The matrix I must use is in a .csv file, and does not include spaces.

```
_, A, R, N, D, C
A, 2,-2, 0, 0,-2 
R,-2, 6, 0,-1,-2
N, 0, 0, 2, 2,-4
D, 0,-1, 2, 4,-5
C,-2,-4,-4,-5,12
```

I apologize if my explanation is confusing. Please let me know if you need any clarification. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can layout the array linearly, you just need to decide whether you want to store rows first or columns first. (e.g. in a row-major implementation, row 1 of a 4x4 matrix would be indices 0-3, row 2 would be 4-7, row 3 would be 8-11, row 4 would be 12-15)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid 2D arrays, you can use 1D array with linear index, and implement convenience helper function to convert 2D coordinate to linear array index - like here [Linear indexing in symmetric matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143657/linear-indexing-in-symmetric-matrices)

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a class / struct and then create a array of objects. This should eliminate your need for a 2D array.